# Guidelines to nullability when bridging Objective-C code

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-swift-bridge

I'm currently a novice in Swift, but I'm a maintainer of an Objective-C framework which is a wrapper around a C library, for which I'd like to have the nicest API possible.

I'm looking at [this kind of code](https://github.com/libgit2/objective-git/pull/622#discussion_r211030499)

```
/// The index checksum
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) GTOID * _Nullable checksum;
```

and wondering if the `nullable` annotation is warranted. Looking at the [underlying C function](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/bfa1f02292d1b637928fe18663a5f2d0aa993400/src/index.c#L600),

```
const git_oid *git_index_checksum(git_index *index)
{
    return &index->checksum;
}
```

it's pretty obvious that, modulo memory allocation failures in [the Obj-C wrapper](https://github.com/libgit2/objective-git/pull/622/files#diff-69d7414b09eb5a169cad5a5365450b75R127),

```
- (GTOID *)checksum {
    const git_oid *oid = git_index_checksum(self.git_index);
    if (oid != NULL) {
        return [GTOID oidWithGitOid:oid];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

this is not nullable.

Or is it ?

Is there some specific guidelines into what's considered acceptable w.r.t nullability when bridging, especially in the face of allocation failures ? Would Swift's reaction be any different if I made that property `nonnull` and memory failed ?

Comment: If `return nil` can’t be deleted, it’s nullable.

Comment: I could rewrite as `return [GTOID oidWithGitOid:git_index_checksum(…)]`, now the only thing that can return `nil` is the initializer itself, hence memory allocation failure.

Comment: I agree. Historically, in Swift 1 _everything_ coming from Objective-C was nullable, because in theory any object reference can be `nil`. So our code was peppered with exclamation marks. Then Apple started hand-tweaking the APIs, introducing the nullable and nonnull attributes, so that if something could not _in fact_ return `nil` as a meaningful value, it was nonnull. Once you've pushed this back to the initializer, that's the situation and you've modernized the API correctly (in my view).